# Handling multiple items in a single MUI/React TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, material-ui

I'm new to JS, React and MUI, and I have a MUI TextField that should accept multiple values like

> 1*10 5*50 13*250 5*50 1*10

> 3*33.33 4*25 3*33.33

on a single line. The elements consist of a positive integers, asterisks and positive floating points/integers. What is the best way to approach this?

I have tried writing an **onChange** handler and a regex for pattern recognition.

`const format = /[1-9]+[0-9]*\*[0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*/g`

This should match all possible values with no leading zeros and possible decimals after the multiplication asterisk. The numbers are arbitrary.

I can't wrap my head around how to disable user input/remove everything that doesn't match this pattern on the fly, since **onChange** changes the TextField value as soon as I press on a button.

Is there a way to mask this?

Are there better ways to do such input formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match the whole string, going by the pattern you're trying to implement, I would do this

```
^(?:\d+\*\d*(?:\.\d*)? ?)*$
```

Here is a working example https://regex101.com/r/o8rvWH/1

If you watch to get the matching pattern you can do this

```
(\d+\*\d*(?:\.\d*)?)
```

Here is a working example https://regex101.com/r/OtfWIp/1

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution which includes most of your requisite.
The leading zero is not left out, but ruled out with regexp.

```
(\b[1-9]\d*\*(?:0\.(?=\S+[0-9])\d+|[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?\b)(?= |$))+
```

example:
https://regex101.com/r/T9I7IV/1

I'm not familiar with javascript so you might need to change the \S.